# Microsoft Edge Detached Elements Tool: Elements remain after refresh

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, devtools

When using the Edge Detached Elements tool it appears that elements will remain in the list even after a refresh.

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9F6O.png)

For example id 143773 in the screenshot was captured, then I refreshed the browser expecting that the element was no longer in memory but yet it still has an idea. I assume this is because the tool is just a report and it's holding onto the sessions findings but I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the expected behaviour of the tool when refreshing

Comment: I dont have a solution sadly, but i have given up edge completly for development.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the description of Detached Elements tool in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/memory-problems/dom-leaks):

> Use the Detached Elements tool to find detached elements that the
> browser cannot garbage-collect, and locate the JavaScript object that
> is still referencing the detached element.

These nodes in your screenshot are not able to be garbage-collected if you have already hit the "Collect garbage" button. So, to these nodes, the tool is used to "find and locate". You'll have to remove the script which prevents the nodes from being garbage-collected by modifying the code elsewhere. Pretty much like your assumption of "just a report".